# update table A with math calculation on table b's content and c'content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

table a is product price table:

```
| productID | country | price |
|-----------|---------|-------|
| 1         | US      | 200   |
| 1         | UK      | 200   |
| 2         | US      | 600   |
```

table b is producy setting table:

```
| ProductID | Nameofsetting | value |
|-----------|---------------|-------|
| 1         | pvalue        | 300   |
| 1         | bvalue        | 200   |
| 2         | bvalue        | 600   |
```

table c is unit price:

```
| unitprice |
|-----------|
| 6.0       |
```

I need to perform update on table A's Price by productID with calculation on (table's bv * table c's unitprice)

example:
If unitPrice = 8.0

table A will update price base on below:

```
| productID | country | price |
|-----------|---------|-------|
| 1         | US      | 1200   |
| 1         | UK      | 1200   |
| 2         | US      | 3600   |
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: all is independent table

Comment: How does `tableb` relate (`join`) to `tablea`?  They would only create a `cartesian product` on the id fields.  Also your sample data doesn't seem to produce your desired results (`unitprice = 6`)...

Comment: @sgeddes  sry data been edited, type wrongly just now, both relate using ProductID

Comment: Please further explain `pvalue` versus `bvalue` -- which `value` do you use in your update -- guessing you use `bvalue` only?  And as previously asked, which database are you using -- sql server, oracle, mysql, postgres. etc?  The `update` syntax with a `join` is different for each database...

Comment: @sgeddes  i only want use bvalue, mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @unit_price DECIMAL

    SELECT TOP 1 @unit_price = UniTPrice
    FROM #TableC;

    UPDATE #tableA
    SET Price = #tableb.Value * @unit_price
    FROM #tableA
    INNER JOIN #tableb ON #tableA.ProductID = #tableb.ProductID
    WHERE #tableb.NameofString = 'bvalue'

    SELECT * FROM #tableA
```

Comment: snstax error on  
    SELECT TOP 1 @unit_price = UniTPrice
        FROM #TableC;

Comment: It's Just an example you have to use your table name and correct column names